# How to make a for loop work for xquery, in the context of 'contains'?

Tags: xpath, xquery

If we have a books.xml file like

```
<books>
    <book isbn="123">
        <collections>
            <collection c="1" />
            <collection c="2" />
            <collection c="3" />
            <collection c="4" />
        </collections>
    </book>
    <book isbn="234">
        <collections>
            <collection c="1" />
            <collection c="2" />
            <collection c="3" />
            <collection c="5" />
        </collections>
    </book>
</books>
```

I want to return all the ISBNs where both books belong to the same collections.

```
declare variable $doc := doc("books.xml");
<samecollections>
{ 
    for $b1 in $doc/books/book
    for $b2 in $doc/books/book
    where $b1 << $b2 and
        every $p in $b1/collections/collection 
        satisfies $p in $b2/collections/collection
    return 
    ...
}
</samecollections>
```

How would I make something like that work?  I've tried inserting a for loop inside the where loop, but nothing worked, so I think I'm just really misunderstanding the syntax of xquery.  Help?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your XQuery processor supports `group by`, so the answer is fairly simple:

```
for $b in $books/book
let $colls-key := string-join($b/collections/collection/@c, '')
group by $colls-key
return element grouped {
    $b/@isbn/string()
}
```

If the collections aren't always ordered in the data, you can order them before generating your key:

```
let $colls-key := 
  string-join(
    for $c in $collections/collection/@c
    order by $c
    return $c)
```

Without `group by` it's a little messier.

```
declare function local:key($collections){
  string-join($collections/collection/@c, '')
};

for $key in distinct-values($doc/books/book/local:key(collections))
return element grouped {
  $doc/books/book[local:key(collections) eq $key]/@isbn/string()
}
```

Depending on the XQuery processor that also may be less efficient, so it's probably not advisable for large data sets. If performance is an issue, then you can look into what optimizations are available for your specific implementation.

Comment: group by isn't supported, and even the latter is throwing a "do you mean to use xqueryp" error at me.   Is there a way to just do a nested loop?  Sort of like `where <condition> for $collection1 if $collection1 is not in /path/to/book2collections`?

Comment: @user1948374 There was a typo in the `local:key` function; you can try that again. XQuery is a query/functional language - you can try to project imperative programming concepts onto it, but I don't recommend it.